# What is the meaning of the "chiaroscuro" sound that was considered ideal in Classical and early-Romantic Italian opera?

Tags: voice, history, performance-practice, opera

Apparently, in Classical and early-Romantic Italian opera (the "*bel canto*" opera repertoire), the ideal kind of vocal colour was a so-called *chiaroscuro* sound. The *chiaro-* part translates as "clear" or "bright", while the *-scuro* part translates as "dark".

However, no two different sources I've found agree as to what is actually meant by *chiaroscuro*. I have found interpretations along the lines of each of the following:

1. *chiaro-* refers to squillo*, while *-scuro* refers to the presence of "chest voice".
2. *chiaro-* refers to the presence of "chest voice", while *-scuro* refers to a low larynx.
3. *chiaro-* refers to the larynx being not too low, while *-scuro* refers to the larynx being not too high.
4. In terms of the aspect of perceived "brightness" or "darkness" of vocal timbre that relates to how much the larynx is (respectively) raised above or lowered below the most relaxed available position for the pitch being sung, *chiaroscuro* refers to "darkening" the timbre as you sing higher. So,

   - for higher notes, *chiaro-* refers to the higher pitch while *-scuro* refers to the darker timbre;
   - for lower notes, *chiaro-* refers to the less dark timbre while *-scuro* refers to the lower pitch.
5. A special case of number 4: *chiaroscuro* refers to a fairly constant absolute height of the larynx.

(Furthermore, one sound that I personally find quite beautiful is the combination of the "clearness" coming from a larynx that is in - or is at most only slightly lowered below - the most relaxed position for the pitch being sung, together with the pleasant "darkness" of a chest-voice-ish sound as in number 1. So I also wonder whether this might have been what the *chiaroscuro* ideal was.)

> > What actually was the *chiaroscuro* sound that was considered ideal in Classical and early-Romantic Italian opera? In fact, did this "ideal vocal colour" even exist, or is the whole thing just operatic folklore? And if there was much belief in an ideal vocal colour, was there ever a reasonably consistent view as to what the ideal vocal colour should be, or was there significant variety of differing opinion?

I would appreciate, please, if anyone giving an answer that claims to know what the ideal *chiaroscuro* sound was could back this up with reasonably convincing historical sources and/or citation of the research of experts in historical performance.

---

**squillo* apparently refers to the "ringing" quality associated with overtones within a certain range which some people take to be around 2-5 kilohertz (roughly A6 to E8) although others seem to take it to be a narrower subrange of this.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that *chiaroscuro* necessarily relates to vocal timbre? Do you have a source that specifically makes that connection?

I ask because, in my experience, *chiaroscuro* pertained to other elements of the composition and production.

Most specifically, it pertains to the relationship between the more neutral (and perhaps static) recitative and the more elaborate (and often longer) arias. So if *chiaroscuro* was the highlighting of light against a dark background, so too would the aria be naturally highlighted against the more neutral recitatives that surround it.

And less commonly, *chiaroscuro* can indicate a production choice, like for example a dark set used to highlight a brightly clothed singer.

But again, my experience with *chiaroscuro* is almost exclusively connected to the alteration of recitative and aria. I'd be curious to hear your source that connected it to vocal timbre.

And speaking of sources, in my own library I see that *The Story of Opera* by James Parakilas agrees with my understanding of this topic. He also cites Piero Jacopo Martello's *Della tragedia antica e moderna* from 1715, of which there is a translated excerpt in both *Opera: A History in Documents* edited by Piero Weiss and Strunk's *Source Readings in Music History*. In the latter, we see:

> Mind, however, that when you end a scene with an exit aria you do not
> begin the very next one with an entrance aria. That would rob the
> music of its chiaroscuro. The instrumental *ricercate* would tumble over each other and instead of helping would hinder the effect.

Thus *chiaroscuro* is really a *formal* concept, not a timbral one.

Comment: Thank goodness for your library! The Wikipedia article is all about timbre and vague. This formal description is much more clearly in line with the meaning of chiaroscuro in painting.

Comment: According to Elson's dictionary - "Light and Shade; the modifications of piano and forte." It's defined as a singing technique focusing on the vocal timbre in wikipedia - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiaroscuro_(music)

Comment: Thank you! You ask, "Do you have a source that specifically makes that connection?" If you mean a historical or an academically reputable source, then no (hence the question). When I said that "no two different sources I've found agree", I'm basically referring to random modern sources that are sufficiently numerous (and uncontradicted by any other sources I've seen) to indicate a generally held and unquestioned belief among today's classical vocal music community in the existence of an ideal "light-dark" vocal timbre. These include Wikipedia (as linked by Tim) and numerous YouTube videos.